# .htaccess URL redirect for sub domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect all queries from sub folder to sub domain with .htaccess?

Including query string (after "/?").

And this should be friendly for SEO (generates 301).

Example:

```
https://example.com/app/?r=dl/catalog/show&param=1
```

redirect to

```
https://sub.example.com/app/?r=dl/catalog/show&param=1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `app/` a real directory?

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: "app" is a real directory

Comment: >What have you tried so far yourself?
My web-application was in root of "https://example.com". Now I created WP site for it, placed new site in a root of "https://example.com" and web-application replaced in sub domain root "https://sub.example.com". But Google still gives links on my "https://example.com" where is no my web-app already and gives 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `app/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# works on Apache 2.4+ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://sub.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

If you're using older Apache 2.2 then use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: it redirects to sub domain but query string (url part after "/?") does not appear in a redirected url

Comment: Unfortunatelly it works only for "http://" queries, but for "https://" still cutting query string part.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Apache ver 2.4.29

Comment: I have already update answer. Make sure you test with only this rule in `app/.htaccess` from a new browser.

Comment: Also this rule redirects ALL "example.com/*" queries but I need ONLY to redirect queries with exact one folder "example.com/app/*"

Comment: No it does not redirect *all* since this is supposed to be in `app/.htaccess` NOT in site root .htaccess. Rules inside `app/.htaccess` can only affect `/app/` URIs

Comment: right, my .htaccess was in a root, now it in "app" folder and works correctly. Your https update also works fine. You are the best!